# How to declare static functions and typedefs public, which cannot be inherited?

Tags: templates, c++11

As many other C++0x users I'm trying to make a smart pointer interface for my projects. Ideally, I'd like syntax like this, hiding both types and `std::make_shared<T>()` calls.

```
Foo::Ptr foo = Foo::shared();
Foo::UPtr unique_foo = Foo::unique();
```

I'd like to place declarations inside a struct to inherit from:

```
template <class T>
struct SmartDefs
{
   typedef std::shared_ptr<T> Ptr;
   typedef std::unique_ptr<T> UPtr;

   template <class... P>
   static Ptr shared(P&&... p)
   {
      return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<P>(p)...);
   }

   template <class... P>
   static UPtr unique(P&&... p)
   {
      return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<P>(p)...));
   }
};
```

Now this works nicely by itself, but when inheritance comes into the picture I get problems, since the typedefs and shared/unique static methods are defined twice. I managed to work around this problem using some ugly macros, private inheritance and require more typing, but I'd like to avoid this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct SmartDefs
{
   typedef std::shared_ptr<T> Ptr;
   typedef std::unique_ptr<T> UPtr;

   template <class... P>
   static Ptr shared(P&&... p)
   {
      return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<P>(p)...);
   }

   template <class... P>
   static UPtr unique(P&&... p)
   {
      return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<P>(p)...));
   }
};

#define DECL_SMART(type) using SmartDefs< type >::Ptr; \
   using SmartDefs< type >::UPtr; \
   using SmartDefs< type >::shared; \
   using SmartDefs< type >::unique

class Foo : private SmartDefs<Foo>
{
   public:
      DECL_SMART(Foo);
      virtual void foo() const { std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl; }
};

class Bar : public Foo, private SmartDefs<Bar>
{
   public:
      DECL_SMART(Bar);
      void foo() const { std::cout << "Bar" << std::endl; }
};

template <class T>
struct Baz : private SmartDefs<Baz<T>>
{
   DECL_SMART(Baz<T>);
   void foo(const T& in) const { std::cout << in << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
   auto foo = Foo::shared();
   auto bar = Bar::shared();
   auto baz = Baz<int>::shared();
   foo->foo();
   bar->foo();
   baz->foo(10);
   foo = bar;
   foo->foo();
}
```

I've tested something like this, but it still gives me ambiguous reference to `shared()`:

```
template <class T>
struct SmartPtr : private SmartDefs<T>
{
   using SmartDefs<T>::Ptr;
   using SmartDefs<T>::UPtr;
   using SmartDefs<T>::shared;
   using SmartDefs<T>::unique;
};

class Foo : public SmartPtr<Foo> {};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you expand on:

> Now this works nicely by itself, but when inheritance comes into the picture I get problems

Do you mean multiple Inheritance of two base classes each inheriting from your SmartDefs class?  Do you mean Inheriting from both the SmartDefs class and a base class which itself inherits from the SmartDefs class?

Either way, your problem is not with C++0x of course, but general ambiguity of base members.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    typedef int ret_type;
    static ret_type go(){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};
struct B
{
    typedef int ret_type;
    static ret_type go(){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};
struct C : public A, public B
{
    typedef int ret_type;
    static ret_type go(){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    C c;

    C::A::ret_type ago = c.A::go();
    C::B::ret_type bgo = c.B::go();
    C::ret_type    cgo = c.go();

    C::A::ret_type static_ago = C::A::go();
    C::B::ret_type static_bgo = C::B::go();
    C::ret_type    static_cgo = C::go();
}
```

So, you need to solve the problem the same way: explicitly disambiguate at call time, or, preferably, overload the functions/typedefs in your derived class.

However, I am not sure I would recommend your solution at all.  In the face of inheritance `Derived::unique()` would return a `unique_ptr<Base>` if Derived did not inherit from your SmartPtr class.  The only "safe" way to implement something like this is with a virtual Create() function (in your case: CreateUnique, CreateShared perhaps).

I would personally prefer to write a global `make_shared` to wrap `std::make_shared` and write my own `make_unique` in the same namespace.

```
A::shared() // replace
make_shared<A>() // with this

A::unique() // replace
make_unique<A>() // with this
```

The few character difference here is trivial compared to not having to inherit every class from SmartDefs, and avoiding the big risk of improper use.

Edit: I forgot to cover that you will lose typedefs for the return type this way.  You could use type_traits, but I actually consider lack of typedef a feature here.  Information aboyt core classes such as std::shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr need not be typedef-ed away, and between `auto`, templates, and `decltype`, there is little need for explicit typedefs.